# Adjusting text box position after data merge

Tags: adobe-indesign

I use InDesign daily to merge addresses onto envelopes. A client wanted the addresses left justified. However, they are very particular that each envelope has the address block centered - every guest has a different length name. After merging, I went in and adjusted every single envelope so the name was centered (by moving the text box left or right), exported to a PDF…and none of those adjustments saved. Every one went back to their original placement. Is this because of where the text box frame is located on the parent page? Any ideas on how to do this? Should I have adjusted each page using paragraph indents instead?